# How to link accounts with different providers using firebase auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm using the flutter firebase library for an authentication that requires facebook , google and email and password sign in,i want to link an account if the email matches with one already in the database, the flow im doing is:
1- User is not loged
2- User sign in with Google
3- Sign in succeed
4- User logout
5- User sign in with facebook with the same email
6- PlatformException ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL

So, im trying to use linkWithCredentials but it requires a currentUser

My code

```
        if (val.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
          final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
              accessToken: val.accessToken.token);
          try {
            var credentialResult =await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
            if(credentialResult.user != null){
                user = credentialResult.user;
            }
            updateUserData(user);
            loading.add(false);
            if (Platform.isIOS) {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            }
            return user;
          } on PlatformException catch (e,stack) {

            print(stack);
            print(e.code);
            loading.add(false);
            switch (e.code) {
              case 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL':
                break;
            }
          } catch (e){
            print('hasdad $e');
          }
        }
```

Also i have read in the source code that i can 'Resolve this case by calling [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail] and then asking the user to sign in using one of them.'

But how i can retrieve the email from the intent of sign in if it throws an exception?

Comment: Why do you do step 4?

Comment: I found my solution for linking accounts in: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1318 hope it helps.